# Use HTML in captions of Vaadin tree items

Tags: vaadin

I am trying to make Vaadin tree items parse the caption as html. I found the method `void   setHtmlContentAllowed(boolean htmlContentAllowed) Sets whether html is allowed in the item captions.` from the documentation and thought the job is done then. But unfortunately, the captions are still escaped as String. Any ideas?

I does not work for me even in this very simple example:

```
class TestExplorer extends CustomComponent{
  val tree = new Tree
  tree.setHtmlContentAllowed(true)
  tree.setCaptionAsHtml(true)
  tree.addItem("<b>test</b>")

  val panel = new Panel()
  panel.setContent(tree)
  setCompositionRoot(panel)
}
```

Comment: I'm using plain java with vaadin 7.6.8 and this feature works as expected either with [implicit captions, explicit captions or properties](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-selection.html#components.selection.captions)(scroll to `Item captions`). Can you share a simple but complete example ([sscce](http://sscce.org)) ?

Comment: I updated a minimal example component in the description. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, with Vaadin 7.6.8 after adding a regular item as well, I get a small white panel, containing a tree with a bold and a non-bold node (see [this screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/Q39QH)). What version are you using?

Comment: I am also using 7.6.8 right now.... I am running out of ideas of possible causes.. any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, weird. I'm curious, does the same happen when using a label, eg `new Label("<b>Html label </b>", ContentMode.HTML)`?

Comment: just tried it out, seems to yield the same result.. Is there any project settings that can lead to this behavior??

Comment: When you say `the captions are still escaped as String` you mean they appear like `<b>Caption</b>` right?

Comment: Then unless scala is escaping those strings somehow, I can't think of any other reason right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was very simple and stupid: the widgetset was not properly recompiled... The "recompile widgetset" button that I used in Eclipse just didn't do the job. Executing the maven command manually solved the problem..